# Which one is more appropriate to use: "send you" or "send to you"?

Tags: grammaticality, indirect-objects, prepositional-objects, dative-alternation, ditransitivity

Are both of the following sentences correct?

> Let me know if there is still something I need to send **to you**.
>
> Let me know if there is still something I need to send **you**.

Which one is more appropriate to use?

Comment: A lot of confusion could have been avoided if you had said "send **to you**" or "send **you**", instead. The **to** relates to **you**, and not to **send**. The emphasis on 'send' is a distraction.

Comment: @Kris Are you suggesting I change the title of question to: _Which one is more appropriate to use: “send to you” or “send you”?_

Comment: No, I'm suggesting to drop the 'send' in the title and emphasise (bold) only 'to you' and 'you' in the question body.

Comment: Related: [What's wrong with “I'll open you the door”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/90530/whats-wrong-with-ill-open-you-the-door/90534) and [Direct and Indirect Objects with the verbs: Give, Buy, and Bring](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/142661/direct-and-indirect-objects-with-the-verbs-give-buy-and-bring)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Both are semantically correct as they are. But compare

> I'll send it to you.

and

> I'll send it you.

The second sentence wouldn't make sense in formal writing, but is found to be understandable in northern England spoken usage. There is also the case of

> I'll send you this thing

Which flow much better without the *to*. In this light it might be more prudent to use **send to you**, as it is more formal, but **send you** in your context would also be accepted.

**EDIT**: I precised my conclusion and added one example following precisions made in the comments.

Comment: I think it depends very much on the context, as the phrase "I will send you an email" is infinitely more pleasing to my ear than "I will send *to* you an email". Also just to throw in my two cents, in certain English dialects (particularly northern) the phrase "I'll send it you" would be understood perfectly, and might even be more popular than the more correct alternative.

Comment: I agree with Andy. I'd actually go as far as to say "I'll send it you" is the more common British English *spoken* usage, although "I'll send it *to* you" might be preferable for more formal written English.

Comment: I agree with Andy F. My wife grew up in northern England and says, for example, "I'll give it you" rather than "I'll give it *to* you", which is standard usage in southern England.

Comment: @gpr is correct, and to clarify I meant that "I'll send it you" (or Antony's "I'll give it you") would not be correct in written English, but would be acceptable in informal spoken language.

Comment: @Maysam: I've given some precision given to me in the comments. Thanks for the additional info @Andy, @gpr and @Anthony.

Comment: In American English, "I'll give it you" will get you strange looks, although folks will probably decipher what it means.  Perhaps this is regional, but I've lived in many regions and never heard this construct in common use.

Comment: I agree with Lynn. "I'll give it you" or "I'll send it you" is not Canadian English either, and I never heard it or anything like it from native English speakers when I was living in London.

Comment: I'm perfectly happy with ***I'll give it you***. But then again I don't have any real problem with [*Go and **open Aunt Ethel the door**!*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/244659/she-showed-me-it#comment529342_244659) Whatever - the usage may fly more in the UK than the US, but I've never particularly associated it with ***Northern*** "dialects".

Answer (score 7):

In addition to what others have said, You can simply find out the difference comparing two sentences:
send somebody something

> We sent Mom flowers for Mother's Day.

send something to somebody/something

> I'll send a copy to you.

Answer (score 2):

*Send you* is fine: *You* is an indirect object.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is more correct at any time, I will send it to you, send followed by the object to who? I will send the dog to school, I will send him to you. But saying I will send you, sounds I will send you to school, I will send you out.

The verb send must give room to destination, medium of sending and object to be send, and if destination should be specified, it comes at end of the statement. So saying "I will send you books", "you books" (also your books) sounds like a possessive noun phrase and as a whole becomes direct object to the verb "send". according to the aforementioned rule, let us give it a destination (you) and medium of sending (via email), constructively the statement will be I will send you books via email to you. It does not sound good, with following the rule it will be I will books via email to you.

Answer (score -3):

The pattern is:

- *to send somebody something*: "send you an email";
- *to send something to somebody*: "send an email to you".

Comment: Your answer is poorly formatted and has misspellings. Please edit it.