# Direct object's placement

Tags: direct-objects, indirect-objects

According to *Longman's English grammar's book*:

> We can use two objects after verbs like give and buy.
>   Instead of: Give the book to me, we can say: Give me the book.
>   lnstead of: Buy the book for me, we can say: Buy me the book.
>   2 Some verbs combine with TO: bring, give, lend, pay, post, sell, send, show, tell, write:
>   Bring that book to me. -, Bring me that book.
>   3 Other verbs combine with FOR: buy, choose, cook, cut, do, fetch, find, get, make, order:
>   Please order a meal for me. -, Please order me a meal.
>   4 We can put it and them after the verb: Give it to me. Buy them for me. Do it for me.
>   With e.g. give and buy, we can say: Give me it. Buy me them. (But not 'Do me it')
>   We say: Give it to John. Buy them for John. (Not *Give John it4*Buy John them') "

Neither the preposition can be dropped nor the construction's placement can be altered if the indirect object is a noun and the direct object is a pronoun:

- **I bought John them** - Wrong
- **I bought them for John** - Correct

Did I get it right??

Comment: Is this different from your other question, http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/371920? I'm having a hard time figuring out why these are separate posts

Comment: Yes, but in "I bought them for John", "John is **not** indirect object. It is object of the preposition "for" not the verb "bought".

Comment: @Bill - Yes. However, is that right, so? - **I gave Paul them** - Wrong. **I gave them to Paul** - Correct?

Comment: "I gave them to Paul" is normal, though some dialects _may_ accept "I gave Paul them".

Comment: @BillJ - How would you define this rule? 

When the direct object is a pronoun and the indirect object is a noun we can't use? Or otherwise?

Comment: Also related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/372021/2085 and http://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a15299%20dative%20alternation